# Proof on 3 equations crossing at one point $(a+b+c=0)$ WITHOUT determinant of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So, as in title, I have to prove that if there are 3 linear equations:

- $ax + by + c = 0$
- $bx + cy + a = 0$
- $cx + ay + b = 0$

and those cross at one point, then $a + b + c = 0$. I know that's true because it is easy to do the proof using matrix determinants. However, in that case I was told that it is possible to do the proof using only linear algebra in matrix. I have no idea how to do it and I'm curious.

Thank you in advance for your effort.

edit:
I think I know the answer. You can correct me if I'm wrong. If we have a matrix of those equations it looks like this: r_1 = [a b c], r_2 =[b c a], r_3 = [c a b]. If we add r_1 and r_2 to r_3 we get a follownig equation: (a+b+c)x + (b+c+a)y + (c+a+b) = 0. The only way this equaton can be true is if a+b+c=0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using only linear algebra in matrix"? I don't know how to interpret "linear algebra in matrix" such that the phrase excludes the usage of determinants

Comment: I think I know the answer. You can correct me if I'm wrong. If we have a matrix of those equations it looks like this:

Comment: It looks like you were trying to answer my question over multiple lines in a comment, but pressing enter submits the comment. You can make things easier by addressing my question in an edit to your question rather than in a comment

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what happened. Thank you Ben, I edited my question as you suggested. Do you think that proves the point?

Comment: Adding the other equations to $r_3$ is a good idea that lets us see pretty quickly that if $a + b + c = 0$, then the equations have exactly one solution. I don't what you're trying to say after that, and the fact that you mention prime numbers at all is very strange.

Comment: Yeah, I went too far with this one. What abut now? Additionaly I like the solutions provided by Raffaele down below.

Comment: Glad you got an answer that you're happy with. As for your answer, I would say that some work is missing. In the case that $a + b + c = 0$,  (but $a,b,c$ are not all zero) it's important to say that the equations $r_1,r_2$ are independent, which means that the resulting system has a unique solution. For the case that $a + b + c \neq 0$, things are a bit more complicated. I would first address the case that $a = b = c$ (where we have an entire line of solutions), and then show that there are no solutions when we have $a + b + c \neq 0$ **and** $a,b,c$ are not all equal.

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean that if I have no information about equations being independent I need to adress also other cases which are: 1) a+b+c≠0 and a, b, c not all equal => no solutions, 2) a+b+c≠0 and a=b=c => an entire line of solutions. Because as I understand at this point, if equations are independent and have exactly 1 solution, then a+b+c=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix of the coefficients and $A|B$ the augmented matrix.

Overdeterminate system like this have solution only if $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A|B)$.

As $\text{rank}(A)=2$ must be $\text{rank}(A|B)=2$ which means that
$$\det(A|B)=\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & -c \\
 b & c & -a \\
 c & a & -b \\
\end{array}
\right|=0$$
which is $$a^3-3 a b c+b^3+c^3=0\to (a+b+c) \left(a^2-a b-a c+b^2-b c+c^2\right)=0$$
satisfied when $a+b+c=0$.
$$.......................................$$
Alternatively
$$
\begin{cases}
 ax + by + c = 0\\
bx + cy + a = 0\\
cx + ay + b = 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Solve the first two equations
$$x=\frac{c^2-a b}{b^2-a c};\;y=\frac{a^2-b c}{b^2-a c}$$
plug in the third
$$\frac{a^3-3 a b c+b^3+c^3}{b^2-a c}=0\to a^3-3 a b c+b^3+c^3=0\\ (a+b+c) \left(a^2-a b-a c+b^2-b c+c^2\right)=0\to a+b+c=0$$